# PHP $client->__soapCall('method', $params); VS. $client->method($params);

Tags: php, soap

I am creating a SOAP client in PHP. Most of my calls look like this

```
$client->__soapCall('method', $params)
```

From what I can tell this is one of two ways to call the methods within the WSDL, the other being:

```
$client->method($params);
```

I have only been able to get the second way to work when calling a method that only requires strings. Using a method that requires an integer gives me this error:

```
The value '' cannot be parsed as the type 'Int32'.'
```

How are these two requests working differently?

Comment: Since the "magic method" approach is designed to be used with WSDL definitions, it may be performing stricter type checks, where the __soapCall method takes a pragmatic PHP-style approach of doing its best to "juggle" types.

Comment: Another possibility is that the arguments to `->method(...)` and the argument to `__soapCall('method', ...)` need to be different. Remember that you can pass multiple separate parameters to the "virtual" method, e.g. `$client->method($a, $b, $c)`; for `__soapCall` these would have to be wrapped in an array because it takes a fixed number of arguments (see the examples on [the `__soapCall` manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php). Without more details of the WSDL you are loading and the contents of `$params`, it's impossible to say exactly what is causing the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Direct call ($client->method()) uses deprecated magical class method __call(). If you are implementing your SoapClient by extending your client class (see example below), you can implement __call() to "callthru" to __soapCall().

```
class mySoapClient extends SoapClient {
    public function __call($method, $parameters) {
        return $this->__soapCall($method, $parameters);
    }
}
```

If you are not implementing your client by extending, using direct call ($client->method()) is a bad idea since it will eventually be dropped out of PHP.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this being deprecated? This page implies the virtual method approach is still considered the default: http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php

Comment: Yes, SoapClient::__soapCall() is going to work in future. Using "direct calls" ($client->method()) are going thru the magical SoapClient::__call() which is [marked as deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.call.php)

Comment: I suspect that is a poorly worded notice, meaning that calling `__call` *explicitly* is deprecated. [The `__soapCall` page](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php) says "Usually, in WSDL mode, SOAP functions can be called as methods of the SoapClient object." Since it's a binary extension, those calls may not actually use the `__call` definition, but rather some internal PHP mechanism.

Comment: That's quite possible also. But better to play safe.

At least exception caught when calling non-existent method is like following:
#0 /var/www/html/.../Client.php(71): SoapClient->__call('fooTest', Array)

This is why I've been avoiding direct calls.

Comment: I've raised a bug suggesting that the wording for this be clarified in the manual: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65586